# Are the following rearrangements of the derivative valid?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, notation

Given : 
$$
y = x^2
$$

The derivative :

$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = 2x
$$

Are the following rearrangements of the derivative valid ?  :

1.
$$
dy=2x(dx)
$$

2.
$$
2xdx=dy
$$

3.
$$
dx=\frac{dy}{2x}
$$

4.
$$
2x^2d=dy
$$

Update,  :

If x = 3 then

$$
\frac{dy}{d(3)} = 2(3)
$$

=

$$
\frac{dy}{3d} = 6
$$

=

$$
dy = 18d
$$

=

$$
y = \frac{18d}{d}
$$

=

$$
y = 18
$$

As cannot compute $x=3$ from $y=18$ in this case then it does not make sense to utilize $dx$ in this way ? dy and dx are composite terms and cannot be split into $(d)(y)$ and $(d)(x)$ ?

Comment: Mainly it depends on the formal setting in which you are working - it is possible to make sense of these expressions and some of them are convenient shorthand (alternatively conventional notation) for statements which could be expressed at greater length and with more apparent precision. However I don't think there is any context in which 4. would make any useful sense.

Comment: @MarkBennet please see question update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, the derivative is defined as a single object $\frac{dy}{dx}$, and no part of that can be split from any other part -- just as you couldn't split one leg of the $x$ from the other three. So none of the rearrangements would be valid.

In certain contexts, you might see $dy$ or $dx$ alone having some meaning, and there might be some relationship to the derivative. But without your having defined what $dy$ or $dx$ means (which you have not in your question), you can't use those objects.

The fourth rearrangement is never, in any context, valid, nor is your computation at the end of the post -- the $d$ is not its own variable (as you surmised).

Answer (score 1):

The first three are valid. At least in some contexts. I have seen these quite a lot in my physics text books and they are often used in conjunction with integration. In a purely mathematical sense this notation is kind of hand-wavy and disliked for that reason. The fourth rearrangement is plain wrong though. In calculus $dx\neq d\cdot x$ for the same reason that $\sin\neq \text {nsi}$. It is just a label.

It is similar to how $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ are names for changes in $x$ and $y$. You could say $\Delta x=0.5$, but $\Delta 3$ doesn't make much sense.

I will now give you an example using finite changes to make the notation more clear. $y$ is a function of $x$, so $\Delta y$ is determined by both $x$ and $\Delta x$. This leads to the usual definition of the derivative. If you take $x=3,\Delta x=0.1$ you can calculate $\Delta y=y(x+\Delta x)-y(x)=0.61$; looking at the ratio $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}=6.1$ you will notice it gets closer and closer to 6 as $\Delta x$ gets closer to zero which is of course equal to $2x$. The derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is **defined** as the number which this fraction is approaching to, even though the fraction itself will never reach it. Similarly $dx$ (kind of) means a change in $x$ which is infinitely small. If you want to fully understand this you will have to understand 'limits' first.

As a final warning you should never split $dy$ and $dx$ in your homework/tests because it can be quite confusing and might not give you the right answer.